# How can I extend unregistered docker images or dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Or maybe instead of using `FROM` there is a way to inject the contents of another dockerfile into the start of my own.

Answer (score 0):

In any case you will need a base Operating System image to source from and then you can use the content of the "other" Dockerfile you want to use and append your own command and form a complete file.

For example the below line will just include the base OS layer:

> FROM ubuntu
>
> MAINTAINER Prasanjit Singh

And then add stuff from the borrowed docker file, say the below lines:

> ENV USER root ENV PASS aiPeekai0AeZ2meephoolais7doo1thu
>
> RUN \   apt-get update && \   apt-get -y install \
>             mysql-server-5.5 && \   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
>
> COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf COPY start.sh start.sh
>
> VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
>
> RUN rm /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d CMD ["/start.sh"]
>
> EXPOSE 3306

And finally add your append your own(if any) and the file looks like this now:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Prasanjit Singh

ENV USER root
ENV PASS aiPeekai0AeZ2meephoolais7doo1thu

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install \
          mysql-server-5.5 && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
COPY start.sh start.sh

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]

RUN rm /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN rm /your/shell/script_or_command.sh # Add your stuff
CMD ["/start.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

And you are done with the Dockerfile. Just build it and get your container launched. Let me know if it you need anything.

Comment: Yea so what I want it a way to do that without copy and paste

Comment: There is no other way to source the contents of another Dockerfile other than using "FROM" or copy pasting the contents to build a fresh file. And I wonder why would that be needed.